# replacing dot in string, but leaving last one

Tags: linux

replace the "." [dots], but leave the last one: e.g.: .txt [there could be random number of dots in the string, even zero, i just need the last one]

$ echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | SOMEMAGIC
someth-ing-something.txt
$

Comment: Cross-posted on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/223402/replacing-dot-in-string-but-leaving-last-one

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\)$/\1\n\2/;s/\./-/g;s/\n/./g'
```

Comment: I like throwing the extra "marker" character for the last dot in there so you don't loose it.  I'll have to remember that trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

F=$1
tail=${F#*.}
head=${F%.*}
removed_dots=$(echo $head| tr "." "-")
mv -iv $1 "$removed_dots.$tail"
```

Comment: You probably want `tail=${F##*.}` (two `#`) and you can do `removed_dots=${head//./-}` (no need for `tr`). You could even re-use the variable `head` instead of using a new variable.

Comment: @Dennis - You are very welcome to improve it. I haven't gotten the hang of all the neat things you can do with `${ ... }` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | sed 's/\./-/g;s/\(.*\)-\([^-]*\)$/\1.\2/'
```

Comment: Fails for `echo 'someth.ing.something.t-xt'`.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure theres a better(regex) way, but you could write a script(python/perl) that takes reads from stdin and finds the last dot, splits it into filename + extension and then replace all dots with dashes in the filename.

At the end concatenate it and spit it out again.

Comment: yup, go with cyrus, =)