# replacing dot in string, but leaving last one

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replacing dot in string, but leaving last one](https://superuser.com/questions/234314/replacing-dot-in-string-but-leaving-last-one)

replace the "." [dots], but leave the last one: e.g.: .txt [there could be random number of dots in the string, even zero, i just need the last one]

$ echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | SOMEMAGIC
someth-ing-something.txt
$

Comment: Cross-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/234314/replacing-dot-in-string-but-leaving-last-one

Answer (score 0):

```
$ file='someth.ing.something.txt'
$ ext=${file##*.}
$ base=${file%.$ext}
$ echo $base
someth.ing.something
$ temp=${base//./-}
$ echo $temp
someth-ing-something
$ newfile=${temp}.${ext}
$ echo $newfile
someth-ing-something.txt
```